# Storing Data in the DOM - Custom Attributes or .data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)

I'm working on a project where I plan on storing small amounts of data in the DOM. I'm specifically using it to attach a numerical value to a DOM element to be easily accessed elsewhere.

Is it better to insert a custom attribute like so:

```
 $('#storeThingsHere').attr('data-count', superArray.length);
```

Or to utilize jquery's .data() function?

```
 $('#storeThingsHere').data("count", superArray.length);
```

I know both can be used, but I want to utilize best practices while also choosing the most efficient method possible. Is there a particular benefit to one over the other, or possibly another better option to store this small amount of data in the DOM?

Comment: I believe the difference is that the `data` method will often store the data internal as opposed to directly in the DOM. I prefer using `attr` just so I can inspect the DOM easily and see the data values. Please correct me if my understanding of the methods is wrong however.

Comment: Good question, I've often wondered the same thing. I tend to use data-attributes but I'd be interested in knowing which is better.

Comment: i had the same thoughts as freakyDaz, but the point why i barely use it is that you cant read already set data attributes with it, when they arent made from jquery itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `data`. Any type can be stored using `data` as jQuery uses an internal object to store them, whereas only strings can be stored using `attr`.

Also, `data()` will most likely be faster due to it not having to reference the DOM for setting/getting, although I've not tested this.